# Apply file filters to string [] of filenames , without opening OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, string, linq, filter, openfiledialog

I want to apply a filter on `string []` of FileNames that i get from `Directory.GetFiles()` without opening it in OpenFileDialog.

Is there any way I can apply all these filters (that i usually would apply to OpenFileDialog)
e.g:

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Bitmap Images (*.bmp)|*.bmp|" +
                          "JPEG Images (*.jpeg, *.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.jpg|" +
                          "PNG Images (*.png)|*.png|" + ...;
```

to the string [].

I basically want to select Folder from FolderBrowserDialog and select only selected files from the Folder - was trying find some way to do this silently(setting parameters to OpenFileDialog but not opening it ).

I just tried the following .:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = folderdialog.SelectedPath; // here I get my folder path 
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Bitmap Images (*.bmp)|*.bmp|" +
                          "JPEG Images (*.jpeg, *.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.jpg|" +
                          "PNG Images (*.png)|*.png";                
            string [] fnms = openFileDialog.FileNames; // I wished this string arry to get poplulated with filtered file list - but doh! Obviously it didn't.
```

Can anyone help me with find a solution to this.
Is there any way to invoke OpenFiledDialog silently ? Or will there be any LINQ query for this problem or anything as such .? [I'm a novice - yet learner]

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think calling Directory.GetFiles more than once will be a good idea because it is an IO operation. I recommend that you do something like:

```
static string[] GetFiles(string directory, params string[] extensions)
{
    var allowed = new HashSet<string>(extensions, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    return Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                    .Where(f => allowed.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f)))
                    .ToArray();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] files = GetFiles(@"D:\My Documents", ".TXT", ".docx");
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got to admit, I like your answer better (and agree with it). My one critique is that you should use `EnumerateFiles` over `GetFiles` in this instance, as you need the IENumerable still for the `where`, although if you have 10k+ files in a directory then it may make sense to only return the correct types

Comment: thanks. We have to read all file names anyway so using EnumerateFiles should not create a difference. Delayed execution helps where reading all elements is not required.

Comment: Thanks @UsmanZafar. Your solution worked well for me.
Marking your solution as answer as its well described and use of `params string[] extensions` impressed me.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Untested but should work

```
var formats = new string[]{"*.jpg","*.mp3"}
formats.SelectMany(format => Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirpath, 
                        format, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the following article:
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Multiple-Filters-Directory.GetFiles-Method.aspx

It is basically a wrapper for the GetFiles function that will take a string very similar to the one you give to the OpenFolderDialog and will return a string array (string[]) of files that match the patterns. (It's just a recursive Direectory.GetFiles)

E.g.:

getFiles(path, "*.bmp|*.jpg") etc.